# Swift 3.0 post request is not sending parameters properly?

Tags: ios, swift, http, http-post

I'm trying to do this post request and I'm getting success as result but user data Full Name, Gender, and DOB are not updating on the server, all are set to null. I think data that I passed is not going to the server properly. Here is my code:

```
func syncPostRequst() -> Bool {

    let plist = PlistHelper()
    var tokenString = plist.getAnyValueFromPlistFile("ACCESS_TOKEN")

    //create the url with URL
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.3:8080/api/User/UpdateBasicUserDetails")! //change the url

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let json: [String: Any] = ["DateOfBirth": "2010.3.3", "FullName": "Anushka Edited iOS", "Gender":"Male"]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    NSLog("JDATASE: \(jsonData)")
    NSLog("JDATASEQQQ: \(JSON(jsonData))")

    //now create the URLRequest object using the url object
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("Bearer \(tokenString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        print("json222:::\(JSON(data!))")
        NSLog("request9900: \(request)")
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                print("json:::\(json)")
                // handle json...
            }

        } catch let error {
            print("ERRROR Caught: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()

    return true
}
```

I'm using Swift 3.0, Does anyone knows any reason for this?

Comment: try to check with postman.

Comment: found out the issue:

Comment: Have to add this part                               
 request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")